# Injecting classes from files not yet imported with tsyringe

Tags: typescript, tsyringe

I want to inject several different instances all having the same token with tsyringe. The constraint I have is that every class is in its own file, and I want them to self register in the DI container. Ex:

`fruit.ts`

```js
export default interface Fruit {
}
```

`apple.ts`

```js
import {registry, singleton} from "tsyringe";
import Fruit from "./fruit"

@singleton
@registry([{token: "Fruit", useClass: Apple}])
export default class Apple implements Fruit {
}
```

`banana.ts`

```js
import {registry, singleton} from "tsyringe";
import Fruit from "./fruit"

@singleton
@registry([{token: "Fruit", useClass: Banana}])
export default class Banana implements Fruit {
}
```

`fruit.processor.ts`

```js
import {injectAll, singleton} from "tsyringe";
import Fruit from "./fruit";

@singleton()
export default class FruitProcessor {
  constructor(@injectAll("Fruit") private fruits: Fruit[]) {
  }
}
```

`index.ts`

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import {container} from "tsyringe";
import FruitProcessor from "./fruit.processor";

container.resolve(FruitProcessor);
```

What I did expect from this was all the fruits to be added to the container and then injected into `FruitProcessor`'s constructor, but all I get is an error saying:

```
Cannot inject the dependency "fruits" at position #0 of "FruitProcessor" constructor. Reason: Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token: "Fruit"
```

Doing some experiments, I can see that this would work if I change it to one of these two options:

1. Adding an import to the fruit classes before injecting FruitProcessor:

```
import "./banana";
import "./apple";
container.resolve(FruitProcessor);
```

2. Moving the registry to a separate file:

```js
import {registry} from "tsyringe";

@registry([
  {token: "Fruit", useClass: Apple},
  {token: "Fruit", useClass: Banana}
])
class Registry {
}
```

None of these options make me happy, since they are prone to errors and mistakes. Is there a way to do this in an automated way, without needing imports nor a separate Registry?